# Delay a href link for some seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little animation which i want to show thats why i want to delay a link. Help would be nice.

```
echo '<td><a href="Detail.php?id='.$row["id"].'" onclick="Splash()"></a></td>';
```

**js:**

```
<script>
function Splash()
{
  setTimeout( function()
  {

  }, 2000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you please include your complete code? You might want to look in to `promise()`.
https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to

```
echo '<td><a href="Detail.php?id='.$row["id"].'" id="spashlink"></a></td>';
```

and add a script

```
 $(function() {
      $('#spashlink').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var self = this;
          setTimeout(function() {
              window.location.href = self.href;
          }, 2000);
      });
 });
```

Comment: @Archer - Of course there is, setTimeout belongs to the window, so `this` inside the timeOut would be the `window`, not the element

Comment: @Archer - No problem, it's hard to keep track of all the javascript weirdness and scope issues.